# How to evaluate a limit with arctan(x)

Tags: calculus, proof-verification

Why  do we have$$\lim _{x\to \,0}\left(\frac{\arctan\left(x\right)-\sin\left(x\right)}{x^3}\right)=-\frac{1}{6}?$$

I used L’Hopital’s Theorem; That result is

$$\lim _{x\to 0}\left(\frac{-\frac{2x}{\left(1+x\right)^2}+\sin\left(x\right)}{6x}\right)$$

So my answer is $\frac{1}{6}$, but the answer to the result using Wolfram Alpha is $-\frac{1}{6}$.

What's wrong?

Comment: Where do you get 1/6 from? If you evaluate the limit, you should get -2/6 + 1/6 = -1/6

Comment: Write $$\arctan(x)-\sin x=\arctan(x)-x+(x-\sin x)$$  and use https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387333/are-all-limits-solvable-without-lh%C3%B4pital-rule-or-series-expansion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT:**

Note that we have

$$\frac{-\frac{2x}{(1+x^2)^2}+\sin(x)}{6x}=-\frac{2}{6(1+x^2)^2}+\frac16 \frac{\sin(x)}{x}$$

and

$$-\frac13+\frac16=-\frac16$$

Comment: Thank you. It was a simple calculation mistake, but I mistakenly made the same mistake several times.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Answer (score 2):

I think the quickest way to see this is by Taylor's theorem.

By the grace of god, the first terms in the Taylor expansions cancel, making this limit finite, since near 0 
$$
\arctan(x)-\sin(x)=x-x^3/3+O(x^4)-(x-x^3/6+O(x^5)
$$
and so 
$$
\frac{\arctan(x)-\sin (x)}{x^3}\sim \frac{-x^3/3+x^3/6}{x^3}=-1/6
$$

Comment: Thank you. but I am not familiar with Taylor's theorem. After studying more, I will refer to your answer.